# Override asp:ValidationSummery MessageBox jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

> ValidationSummery of asp.net shows MessageBox when validation fails
>   after clicking the Save button in Form of my Project.

I am concern about following Control:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ShowMessageBox="true" ValidationGroup="InfoCarrier" ShowSummary="false" HeaderText="Please fill the valid value in red marked field(s)." EnableClientScript="true" DisplayMode="BulletList" runat="server" />
```

I am trying to override the MessageBox which shows when validation fails.Actually want to change the way it displays and apply some customised jquery and css.

I have already override alert ,actually had believe it would be alert which comes as the message box when validation fails.But fails to collect.

My Attempt was such :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(
 window.alert=function(){
Managealert();//My Customised Function.
});
</scirpt>
```

Please Guide me how to override Message-box which comes as a result of ValidtionSummery.

Thanks in Advance for Kind Cooperation.

Comment: When you say you want to change how it displays, you mean the look of it when rendered in the browser? If so, use CSS?

Comment: Actually i worked over it and get to know.. Message Box created by the Asp:ValidaitonSummery can't be overriden as it is the static method which work for it. If i found any way to get control to override the MessageBox ,i can apply css and even can do more.